# django with apache ldap backend auth, get logged in username and ldap group & hide detail based on group (mod_ldap)

Tags: python, django, apache

im using Django with Apache and LDAP backend auth, my http conf is as below:

```
LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
#
<Location />
  AuthName "Please enter your domain credentials."
  AuthBasicProvider ldap
  AuthType basic
  AuthLDAPUrl "ldap://example.com:389/DC=example,DC=com?sAMAccountName"
  AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=serv,OU=Service Accounts,DC=example,DC=com"
  AuthLDAPBindPassword XXXX
  AuthLDAPBindAuthoritative off
  LDAPReferrals off
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Which when i now load my site i get a basic auth prompt which is great, what id like to be able to do now is to receive the logged in username, ive searched and tried a few things such as:

```
LoggedInUser = request.user.username
```

which gives me a request is not defined message (i have import requests at the top)

```
LoggedInUser = os.getenv["REMOTE_USER"]
```

which gives me TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

does anyone know what i need to be using?

i also need to hide certain urls from users if they are not in the correct ldap group, so would need to get the users AD groups aswell from the session

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation topic ["Authentication using REMOTE_USER"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/auth-remote-user/#authentication-using-remote-user), in order to use Apache authentication, you must include a specific middleware:

> ## Configuration
>
> First, you must add the `django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware` to the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting after the `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware`:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    '...',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware',
    '...',
]
```

> Next, you must replace the `ModelBackend` with `RemoteUserBackend` in the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` setting:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend',
]
```

If you are already doing this without success, and given you need more granular access controls, I would just write a custom authentication backend and ditch mod_ldap altogether. [Writing a custom authentication backend is really easy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend). The key is to get the python ldap module working before writing the backend.

In order to access `request.user` you must be inside a Django view. For example:

```
def index(request):
    user = request.user
    return render(request, 'template.html', {"user": user})
```

And in the `template.html` file:

```
<h1>Hi, {{ user }}</h1>
```

Comment: ive copied this snippet https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2899/ i have no errors but i dont actually know how to use it? how do i login or set which pages required login?

Comment: You must register your backend at `settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`, look at the the link about writing a custom backend, just pretend you wrote it yourself and follow the rest of the instructions there.

Comment: i created a seperate question for it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298958/django-active-directory-backend-no-attribute-getitem i got the settings configured... thanks

Comment: Your both links are broken.

Answer (score 3):

Per request WSGI environ key/values are found in Django `request.META` object. Thus try:

```
request.META['REMOTE_USER']
```

Whether what Apache passes through to you is in format you expect is a different issue. You may find what you want in other variables passed through. See:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#exposed