# django active directory backend no attribute __getitem__

Tags: python, django, active-directory

I've been trying to use the snippet found here https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2899/ to have an ldap back end, however when I now login to my admin page I get the error

```
TypeError at /admin/login/
'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://it.intranet.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
Django Version: 1.9.6
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
Exception Location: /var/www/infternal/infternal/backend.py in get_or_create_user, line 69
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.5
Python Path:    
['/var/www/infternal',
 '/usr/lib64/python27.zip',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 18 May 2016 11:54:09 +0000
```

I presume this is happening because I haven't successfully connected to the ldap server?

How can I test this?

The backend code is copied exactly from the snippet.
my settings.py is as below

The only thing I wasn't sure of was the AD_CERT_FILE field, I don't know where this is or what to put for that, but as I wasn't using ssl I presumed it wasn't needed?

```
# active directory authentication module
AD_DNS_NAME = 'example.domain.com'   # FQDN of your DC (using just the Domain Name to utilize all DC's)
# If using non-SSL use these
AD_LDAP_PORT=389
AD_LDAP_URL='ldap://%s:%s' % (AD_DNS_NAME,AD_LDAP_PORT)
# If using SSL use these:
#AD_LDAP_PORT=636
#AD_LDAP_URL='ldaps://%s:%s' % (AD_DNS_NAME,AD_LDAP_PORT)
AD_SEARCH_DN = 'DC=example,DC=domain,DC=com'
AD_NT4_DOMAIN = 'example.domain.COM'
AD_SEARCH_FIELDS = ['mail','givenName','sn','sAMAccountName','memberOf']
AD_MEMBERSHIP_ADMIN = ['ITService_App_Admin']   # this ad group gets superuser status in django
# only members of this group can access
AD_MEMBERSHIP_REQ = AD_MEMBERSHIP_ADMIN + ['GS_ITsupport',
                                           'GS_ITDevelopment',]
AD_CERT_FILE = '/certs/certfile'    # this is the certificate of the Certificate Authority issuing your DCs certificate
AD_DEBUG=True #Set to false for prod, Slows things down ALOT
AD_DEBUG_FILE='/tmp/ldap.debug'


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'infternal.backend.ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', #Comment out to prevent authentication from DB
)
```

Comment: call me on Google Hangouts, may be I can help you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

It is not your fault, the TypeError message you got is not very informative.

This particular snippet requires you to mirror your relevant AD groups in Django (you must create the same groups in Django using the admin). The groups should not have the same name, instead, the following convention is used (from a comment in the source):

> Our AD groups were mirrored with the Django groups but prefaced with "ID " (notice the space)

If your Django group is named "ITsupport" then your AD group must be called "ID ITsupport" and so on.

If you want to modify this behavior, you must change the regular expression at line 142:

```
re.compile(r'^CN=ID (?P<groupName>[\w|\d|\s]+),')
```

For example:

```
re.compile(r'^CN=(?P<groupName>MyADGroup|MyOtherAdGroup|AndSoOn),')
```

Just replace the original expression with a list of your AD groups separated by a pipe (`|`). You still have to create the groups using the Django admin or the shell.